# Help understanding why my question was "bad"?

Tags: discussion

Recently my account was question banned due to what I believe was a marked as a "bad" and closed question.

The question I asked involved a privacy issue that blocks :visited CSS tags. I had no way of knowing this since I have only been using CSS and Javascript for about a year, and this bug has been patched on all modern browsers since 2010. Other community members were also puzzled by the mis displaying of the CSS tag. The question was closed soon after being asked as "not a real question."

[background-image: for :visited links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202856/background-image-for-visited-links)

How can I fix the question? What should I keep in mind when trying to fix this question?

Thanks,
I appreciate your input

Comment: Of note: That one single question is not why you were post-banned. The post-ban is more likely caused by the total of your participation.

Comment: Just a clarification: While the question ban algorithm is intentionally kept secret, you weren't banned for just one closed question. I can see a total of 5 closed questions from your account, and there might be more (I can't see deleted questions), they all count towards the ban. That said, good job on asking what to fix instead of just complaining about the ban as people usually do.

Comment: Hi Bart. Thanks for the response. If I deleted a question that was a duplicate, could that contribute to my ban?

Comment: Yes, but only contribute. Not cause. It's a single signal of "poor quality" in a larger whole.

Comment: That seemed like an okay question to me, did you edit it after it was closed?

Comment: Hi Asad, I only added the EDIT blurb at the end after it was closed.

Comment: Hi Yannis, Thanks for the response. I agree, I did have many closed questions. I will have to work on fixing them. Can a question be reopened if I fix it? Will anyone see the changes I make? Thanks again

Comment: @user1530249 Yes, a question can be re-opened if improved, it only takes 5 re-open votes from users with more than 3000 rep (same with close votes). Every edit brings new attention to a question, and you only need a single re-open vote for the question to enter the review queues, where a lot of people with the ability to close and re-open questions hang out.

Answer (score 4):

That particular question doesn't seem to ask a whole lot you could not have resolved yourself.

> Is it possible to add the background-image: property to visited links?
>
> ```
> a.coolLinks:visited{
>   background-image:url("http://www.ledr.com/colours/black.jpg");
> }
> ```

That is: is it possible to use the code below? Well, try it. Does it work? Then yeah, it works. And if not... then you might have had a question. I.e. I'm trying to achieve X, I have tried Y, but it didn't work (include details).

In the form as above, it is not really much of a question and that's what caused it to be closed, I assume.

As for your ban, you seem to have a fair share of closed questions, maybe some deleted ones (?). That will have caused your ban. Not this single instance.

Comment: Hi Bart. Thanks. Are you aware if there is there a guide to constructing good questions? I like the style you posted "I'm trying to achieve X, I have tried Y". I have received question asking privileges back but want to read into constructing better questions first.

Comment: There is [this blog post by Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page, and the overused but still informative [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). That should provide enough reading material for now.

Comment: Thanks, can I change the question title of my closed questions? is this considered 'ok' practice?

Comment: If that somehow improves them, by all means go ahead. Improvements are always welcome. Don't completely change your questions into something they are not though. (i.e. don't change the question you're asking).